# EOS claim procedure if an incompatible wallet was used to partecipate

Tags: tokens, token-distribution, claim

Is there any way to interact with the contract for claiming tokens if I've taken part of the token distribution from an incompatible wallet?

Is exporting private keys and importing in MEW or other compatible wallet the only way to operate or are there alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no incompatible wallets. Every Ethereum address allows you to interact and claim/register your tokens through MEW. 
Another alternative is to use Exodus wallet which gives you the option to register your wallet.

Comment: Yes, I'm using Exodus and already registered my tokens, The problem is that I contributed to the ICO directly from Exodus. And it seems that from there it's not allowed to claim tokens.
I'm wondering if there is any way to do the claim without moving the private key to MyEtherWallet or Metamask

Comment: No other ways. Only few wallets like MetaMask allow you to claim eos tokens.